# How to change the position in CIRCULAR CONTENT CAROUSEL WITH JQUERY by tympanus

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am Using CIRCULAR CONTENT CAROUSEL WITH JQUERY by tympanus , in this using jquery plugin left position is increasing 200px for every time . But i need only 170px. How can i Change in that plugin. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open `jquery.contentcarousel.js` and go to `line 165`

```
cache.itemW = $items.width(); //item width
```

cache.itemW is apply as left to the items, here you can give manual size